# The first argument of the `$location#search()` call must be a string or an object

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

Im working on an angularjs and MVC app, my app works fine but im getting an error in my console.

> #### Error: $location:isrcharg
>
> #### Wrong $location.search() argument type
>
> The first argument of the `$location#search()` call must be a string or an object

this is my angularjs navigation service:

```
 self.goBack = function () {
        $window.history.back();
    }

    self.navigateTo = function (path, params) {
        if (params === null) {
            $location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path);

        }
        else {

            $location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path).search(params);
        }

    };

    self.refreshPage = function (path) {
        $window.location.href = MyApp.rootPath + path;
    };

    self.clone = function (obj) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
    };

    self.querystring = function (param) {
        if ($location.search !== null)
            return $location.search()[param];
        else
            return null;
    };

    self.resetQueryParams = function () {
        $location.url($location.path());
    };

    return this;
};
```

this above code is a common factory, so after injecting it to my controler thats how i navigate
inside angular i use  `viewModelHelper.navigateTo("/home");`
then if i want to navigate to mvc page i use

```
 viewModelHelper.refreshPage("index");
```

im getting error in this code when im navigationTo

```
$location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path).search(params);
```

Comment: [Error: $location:isrcharg](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/isrcharg). To resolve this error, ensure that the first argument for the $location.search call is a string or an object. You can use the stack trace associated with this error to identify the call site that caused this issue.

To learn more, please consult the [$location api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) docs.

Comment: My guess is `params === undefined` and the code is checking for `params === null`.

Comment: @geordeawg it seems you are right, i did put a console log on my navigateTo method... my params is not defined, but why is it navigation though..

Comment: How do i solve this undefined problem, im new to angular

Answer (score 2):

> my params is not defined. How do i solve this undefined problem

```
self.navigateTo = function (path, params) {
    if ( ̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶s̶ ̶=̶=̶=̶ ̶n̶u̶l̶l̶  !params) {
        $location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path);
    }
    else {
        $location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path).search(params);
    }
};
```

OR

```
self.navigateTo = function (path, params) {
    if (params) {
        $location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path).search(params);
    }
    else {
        $location.path(MyApp.rootPath + path);
    }
};
```

In the above example, the code will only execute the `.search` method if the `params` variable is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

In JavaScript, a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value is a value that is considered  `true` when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) unless they are defined as [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (i.e., except for `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`).

For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference - truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)